# .htaccess mod_rewrite redirect directory to URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have problem with redirection directory to URL. I try few ideas from here and nothing working with my problem.

I want redirect directory adres to URL like:

```
http://www.x.yz/en to http://www.x.yz/en/site.html
http://www.x.yz/en/ to http://www.x.yz/en/site.html
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^en/?$ /en/site.html [R=301,L]
```

Put the above rule inside `htaccess` file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, everything works as it should.